# c: expected a statement

Tags: c, if-statement, compiler-errors, syntax-error

When I compile the below code, I get the error:

```
(line 64) expected a statement 
(line 71) warning: parsing restarts here after previous syntax error.
```

line 64 corresponds to the else corresponding to the

```
if (num_bins < blockDim.x * gridDim.x)
```

(I commented the exact line in the code below ).

in previous posts, the error was an unnecessary semicolon after the if, which I do not have. further, all my brackets match. What is causing this error and how can I fix it?

```
__global__ void histogram_shared_kernel(unsigned int *input, unsigned int *bins,
                                 unsigned int num_elements,
                                 unsigned int num_bins) {
    
    __shared__ unsigned int shBins[num_bins];
    int tx = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    int stride = blockDim.x * gridDim.x; //stride amount = total number of threads
    //all threads handle blockDim.x * gridDim.x amount of elements

    //initialize all threads to zero
    //if the number of bins < number of threads, we just need an if statment
    if (num_bins < blockDim.x * gridDim.x){
        if (tx < num_elements){
            shBins[tx] = 0;
        } //end if
    } //end if
    __syncthreads();
    //if the number of bins > number of threads, we  need an if statment and a for loop
    else{ //corresponds to line 64
        if (tx < num_elements){
            for (int bin = tx; bin < size; bin = bin + blockDim.x){
                shBins[tx] = 0;
            }
        }
    }//end else
     __syncthreads();
    //end initialization phase
    //begin computation
    while (tx < num_elements){
        atomicAdd( &shBins[input[tx]], 1); //increment the corresponding bin by 1 (the 2nd arg)
        tx += stride;
    } //end filling in shBins
    //wait for all other threads to finish
    __syncthreads();

    //now, merge results of each privatized copy
    if (tx < num_bins){
        atomicAdd(&(bins[tx]), shBins[tx]);
    }//end if
}//end kernel
```

Comment: You can't put a `__syncthreads()` (or any other statement in C or C++) in between the if-block and the else-block.

Answer (score 2):

You may not place a separate statement between if and else like you are doing

```
if (num_bins < blockDim.x * gridDim.x){
    if (tx < num_elements){
        shBins[tx] = 0;
    } //end if
} //end if
__syncthreads();
//if the number of bins > number of threads, we  need an if statment and a for loop
else{ 
//...
```

That is there is no separate statement else without if. But this statement

```
__syncthreads();
```

splits the if-else statement into two separate statements.